# Why is that when float is specified to the clear div, its parent container's border does not recognize it?

Tags: html, css, css-float

example:

Html

```
<div id = parent>
      <div class = "clearDiv"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.clearDiv
{
      width:      1000px;
      height:     1px;
      float:      left;
      clear:      both;
      visibility: hidden;
}
```

with the `float: left` property specified, its parent div does not recognize it, the therefore the parent div #parent has a height that is pretty much zero, why?

Comment: Using `float` pulls the floated element out of the normal page flow. The ancestor/inheritance relationship of the elements remains, but you sever the containment relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `overflow:auto;` CSS style to parent container element.

To parent container they don't provide dimensinal infomation. They just interact with their siblings (or other floated elements). Hence **float**. They can be anything, anywhere and of any size. Container doesn't really care because they're floating...

Comment: actually isn't there a better approach w/o the overlow to parent? I mean that would make the parent container at scroll bars when the window resizes to small...which i don't want.

Comment: You can always set overflow to `visible` just as well to avoid parent element from getting scrollbars. But I still think that `auto` does the trick just fine. When content is larger than window's viewport, the whole document will get scrollbars, not your div.